# Prism AutoWireViewModel throws exception in release mode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I am writing a WPF MVVM application using prism and MahApps.

When I run my code in debug mode, everything works fine.

When I run it in release mode, I get `Set property 'Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel' threw an exception`

Here's my window control in the .xaml

```
<ma:MetroWindow x:Class="RoviPutt.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;assembly=GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop"
        xmlns:ma="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Icon="/images/favicon.ico"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="RoviPutt" Height="750" Width="1200" Background="#252525">
```

In the .xaml.cs

```
namespace RoviPutt.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And in my ViewModel

```
namespace RoviPutt.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase, IDropTarget
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the inner exception?  Also, your VM is private.

Comment: Could be some solutions here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23687556-d9af-4799-aece-2e565dda9345/autowireviewmodel-exception?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: @BrianLagunas: I am sure you meant to say internal. Classes without type modifier are internal by default. Members are private by default

Comment: @Tseng Yes, you are correct. I was point this out as it can cause issues when using the modularity feature of Prism, or if trying to resolve VMs that reside in a different assembly than the View.

Comment: @arazzy I read somewhere in prism documentation that in order for container to auto wire the views with viewmodels, all the view related pages should be inside Views folder and viewmodels should be inside viewmodels folder and view should be named like xxxPage.Xaml and viewmodels like xxxPageViewModel.cs . So in your case it should be MainWindowPage.xaml and MainWindowPageViewModel.cs.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @CodeNoob the name does not have to contain the word "Page".  The OP's current naming convention is correct, MainWindow -> MainWindowViewModel.  The namespaces look correct too.  Are these classes in the same assembly?

Comment: @Brian lagunas Please  see the link. There’s also another naming convention to follow, which is about the name of the files:

The View should end with the Page suffix (like MainPage).
The ViewModel should have the same name of the View, plus the ViewModel suffix (so, for example, the ViewModel connected to a page called MainPage will be named MainPageViewModel).http://wp.qmatteoq.com/prism-and-universal-windows-app-the-basic-concepts/

Comment: @CodeNoob No, the View name does not have to end in the suffix "Page".  It can be anything.  For example; a view named Customers with a CustomersViewModel.  This link is more complete: http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this one should have been:

- Probably you are using IRegionManager from the wrong component
  instead of
  `using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions`
  you should have
  `using Prism.Regions`